# UIToolbar center UIBarButtonItem vertical

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uitoolbar

I'm working on a Monotouch project, where I have designed the UIImagePickerController with the CameraOverlayView.
In then bottom I have an UIToolBar, and on iPhone5 the toolbar is large. Here the camera-button is centeret vertical, but my cancel button isn't.
[image]

What can I do to center it? 
The code for creating it is:

```
        mCameraToolbar = new UIToolbar();

        UIBarButtonItem cancel = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel);
        cancel.Clicked += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mPicker.DismissViewController(true, null);
            if(mImgView.Image == null)
                NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
        };
        UIBarButtonItem camera = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Camera);
        camera.Clicked += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mPicker.TakePicture();
        };
        mCameraToolbar.SetItems(new UIBarButtonItem[]{ 
            cancel, 
            new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace), 
            camera, 
            new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace), 
            new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace) 
        }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible with a simple UIBarButtonItem. But you can try doing it with adding a view as a container. You only have to pass a UIView when creating a new UIBarButtonItem like this:

```
UIView containerView = new UIView();
containerView.Frame = new RectangleF(0f,0f,150f,YOUR_TOOLBAR_HEIGHT);
UIButton buttonAnuller = new UIButton();
buttonAn.SetTitle("Annuler",UIControlState.Normal);
buttonAn.Bounds = new RectangleF(0f,0f,150f,30f);
buttonAn.Center=new PointF(containerView.Frame.Width/2,containerView.Frame.Height/2);
containerView.Add(buttonAn);
UIBarButtonItem itemWithView = new UIBarButtonItem(containerView);
```

In this code snipped a containerView is created. After that a Button is created an added to the containerView. The last step is only creating a new UIBarButtonItem with the container as parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of figuring out how to tame the Toolbar I would suggest to just going without it, you can easily get that result with a custom view which has the two buttons inside.

PS: Don't use anonymous delegates. Otherwise your code will leak memory.